# simple straight lines detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, lines, edge-detection, straight-line-detection

I'm looking for a **simple** algorithm for finding straight lines on the image. Not necessarily fast, just a working concept. I've done my homework and already found several approaches to the problem (e.g. combination of [Canny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) and Hough transform or [LSD](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/gjmr-lsd/)) but couldn't find anything relatively easy to implement.

My input data are grayscaled 8 bpp images.

Comment: It'll be quicker for you to implement Sobel, Roberts, or some other simple operator rather than Canny. geek_girl named the two workhorse solutions for the problem: Hough and RANSAC. Hough is relatively easy to implement--perhaps you could give it a try and then post your code if you run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

The Hough Transform is a good way to do this. Also try RANSAC algorithm which is more robust to outliers.